# Want to create hover link menu in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, onhover

heyy,

i want to create some hover background link when mouseover in jquery !!!

when the mouse over on " .nav Menu nav a ", I add addclass " .hover " and when mouse out removeClass " .hover "

more info on my fiddle -> [demo JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axelschouten/t6d4hvkg/)

HTML :
>
>

> ```
>             <a href="inc/about/" class="Load frame" id="html" data-html="about">
>              <div class="hover"></div> about
>             </a>
>
>             <a href="inc/porject/" class="Load frame" id="html" data-html="project">
>               <div class="hover"></div> project
>             </a>
>
>             <a href="inc/story/" class="Load frame" id="html" data-html="story">
>              <div class="hover"></div> story
>             </a>
>
>             <a href="inc/contact/" class="Load frame" id="html" data-html="contact">
>               <div class="hover"></div> contact
>             </a>
> ```

CSS :

> ```
> .navMenu nav {
>
>       width: 100%; height: auto;
>       list-style-type: none; margin: auto auto;
>       text-align: center;
>
>     }
>
>
> .navMenu a {
>
>       height: 4em; width: 100%; 
>       text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase;
>       text-align: center; display: block;
>       line-height: 4em; font-weight: normal;
>       font-size: 1em; color: rgba(238,79,87,1); 
>       position: relative; z-index: 100;
>
> }
>
> .hover{
>
>     /* add background, width, height, ect... */
>
> }
> ```

JS:

> function hoverLi(){
>
> ```
>         $(".navMenu a").hover(function(){
>
>           $(this).stop(true, true).addClass("hover");
>
>         },function(){
>
>           $(this).removeClass("hover");
>
>
>         });
>
>
>       }
> ```

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not simply `.navMenu a:hover` in CSS?

Comment: @Reeno because i want to animate left position to 0% from 100% like keyframes but in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here is JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/t6d4hvkg/4/

use css selector `:hover`

It's a pseudoclass

update your CSS:

```
.navMenu nav {

  width: 100%; height: auto;
  list-style-type: none; margin: auto auto;
  text-align: center;

}


.navMenu a {

  height: 4em; width: 100%; 
  text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center; display: block;
  line-height: 4em; font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em; color: rgba(238,79,87,1); 
  position: relative; z-index: 100;

}

.navMenu nav:hover{

background:#000000;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
color:white;

}
```

Comment: Yes but it's CSS, i want use javascript hover !

Comment: @axelschouten But why? Not all browsers support javascript and user can opt out to disable javascript, while CSS cannot be disabled. It also slow down the page loading time, resulting to better SEO.

Comment: yes i know, but i must do an animation with easing on hover and i prefer use Jquery hihi :o)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6d4hvkg/4/ Here is jsfiddle with easing animation with css only

Comment: lol thanks but i know to do this but i want to do with javascript :{o

Comment: in fact i want an animation who to play with position and left.
Firstly, left at 0% and when i mouseover i want that "div class=hover ",do 100% position left

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you insist to use jQuery then you just need to remove your function and leave just this part:

```
$(".navMenu nav a").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Check out this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6d4hvkg/3/)..

Comment: hooooo thanks thanks :D but now i want animate left right background

Comment: what do you mean by `animate left right background` ?

Comment: @axelschouten add `transition: all 1s;` to the css selector that needs to be animated

Comment: @user26409021user i mean that mouseover the "div class="hover" start to 0% at left and from 100% at left !!!!! you know what mean ? like keyframes hover

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add a background color to your hover class like so:

```
.hover{
  background-color:#eee;
```

}

and then call `document.ready function`, passing your HoverLi function to it.